# Exclude Grails 3 plugins before packing war file

Tags: grails, gradle, build.gradle, war, grails-3.1

I want to exclude some Grails 3.1.9 Plugins for deploying, because i do not need them in production. I know i can use `provided` instead of `compile` but then all dependencies of this Plugin are also excluded even if a other plugin have the same dependencies.

**Example:**

- Plugin 1 depends on `mail.jar` and `log.jar`
- Plugin 2 depends on `log.jar` and `math.jar`

snippet of `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies{
  compile "com.plugin1"
  compile "com.plugin2"
}
```

If i run `gradle war`, in the resulting archieve file I can find `mail.jar`, `log.jar` and `math.jar`. In production I do not need `plugin1` so I change dependencies-block like this:

```
dependencies{
  provided "com.plugin1"
  compile "com.plugin2"
}
```

After `gradle war` it only includes math.jar.

How can i change the `build.gradle` file in order to pack a war- file which includes only `plugin2` and all it is dependencies: `log.jar` and `math.jar`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems like a bug. And most probably a gradle bug. But I would make an issue first in grails-core (on github)

Comment: @HansBogaards, look [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/war_plugin.html) i think it is not a bug.

Comment: Paragraph 47.4 gives the answer, I think. Declaring plugin1 as 'com.plugin1@jar' should work.

Comment: @HansBogaards, i tried to mark some plugins with `@jar`, but then they are also excluded if i start with `run-app`. I need a way to declare some plugins as excluded only for `war` packing.